# Access two excel files using single macro

Tags: excel, vba

I have macro, using which i am trying to open a excel file then make some validation in the file that is opened. And Open another excel file and put the validation results(of excel file 1) in the form of report in the 2nd Excel.

So the task i have to do here is:

1. Open Excel file 1
2. Script to validate data in excel file 1.
3. Open Excel file 2
4. Enter the results in it.

Here i am able to open two excel files but not able to create pointers to them. Such as

if i use Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").value 'this picks data from Excel file 1.

But to access Excel file 2 what do i need to write, is this something like this:

Sheets("!Sheet1").Range("A1").value

Please help me to fix this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Application.Workbooks("create-a-macro").Worksheets(1).Range("A1").Value = "Hello"

Visit http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/workbook-worksheet-object.html

Comment: Thank you SNathan. That is what i wanted. :)